# Class method using switch with default triggers not all code paths returns value

Tags: powershell, class, powershell-5.0

Using a very simple class with one method

```
Class Bagel{
    static [int] SwitchTest([int]$value){
        switch ($value){
            1 {return $value + 1}
            2 {return $value * 2}
            default{return 0}
        }
    }
}
```

This won't compile because it gets an error with the method `SwitchTest`

> Not all code path returns value within method.

I completely get what that means. Where I am stumped is what path would cause this to fail? The `default` should capture any condition not matched right? i can make the error go away if I change it to this:

```
Class Bagel{
    static [int] SwitchTest([int]$value){
        switch ($value){
            1 {return $value + 1}
            2 {return $value * 2}
            default{return 0}
        }

        return -1
    }
}
```

This executes just fine. Adding that last `return` *seems* useless to me. I don't think this is a bug. Just curious if someone can let me know what I don't get about this. Under what condition can I get that last static method to return -1?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455833/powershell-5-0-class-method-returns-not-all-code-path-returns-value-within-meth) talks about the same issue with a `for` loop. I understand why that one does not work.

Comment: `switch` is the loop. If it will do zero iterations, then no return is taken.

Comment: *Under what condition can I get that last static method to return -1?* https://tio.run/##ZZE9b8IwEIZ3/4p3YEhaGTVRJySkAkOnfqipWBCDSY5i1UqofYaB8ttTN0lL0t5k3fPo/J69r45k3Y6MqeuFUc5hrt7InARCOVasc6x0yWtkR8357pUcR01jdFDGU9yajd0IiP6B70pwssTelmgxrpGcB0b617hCOjQK2ipv@Ee7udCz@D12UCaiBQFlxPI5m1tS7/sqRIdcKqvVxhDam@RDVRBeSBWQs5x1VaJNr7fdNpD0gds0xmWr0QFT3IfRw2E9Pp4xW73xTG68MKRsFPfpshk8xV3XDlnxiSfP8tEbI8Sq@Yn1ZNJ7@RBB1PUX

Comment: That seems extreme but you made it work. Thanks again @petserai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PowerShell `switch` effectively is a loop, thus it can be executed zero times. That means that no clause from it will be executed included `default` one.

Although it is impossible for `[int]` to have value, which trigger `switch` zero times, but with PowerShell breakpoints you can hook variable read and replace its value with something else entirely on the fly:

```
Class Bagel{
    static [int] SwitchTest([int]$value){
        switch ($value){
            1 {return $value + 1}
            2 {return $value * 2}
            default{return 0}
        }

        return -1
    }
}

Set-PSBreakpoint -Variable value -Mode Read -Action {
    if($value -eq 42) {
        $v = Get-Variable value
        $v.Attributes.Clear()
        $v.Value = @()
    }
} | Out-Null

[Bagel]::SwitchTest(42)
```

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##ZZE9b8IwEIZ3/4p3YEhaGTVRJySkAkOnfqipWBCDSY5i1UqofYaB8ttTN0lL0t5k3fPo/J69r45k3Y6MqeuFUc5hrt7InARCOVasc6x0yWtkR8357pUcR01jdFDGU9yajd0IiP6B70pwssTelmgxrpGcB0b617hCOjQK2ipv@Ee7udCz@D12UCaiBQFlxPI5m1tS7/sqRIdcKqvVxhDam@RDVRBeSBWQs5x1VaJNr7fdNpD0gds0xmWr0QFT3IfRw2E9Pp4xW73xTG68MKRsFPfpshk8xV3XDlnxiSfP8tEbI8Sq@Yn1ZNJ7@RBB1PUX)